# video artifacts

Tags: video, dslr

My wife is using her Panasonic lumix to shoot video. She gets great shots of wildlife. The issue is that shots of flying birds, ducks or eagles or whatever is happening, appear to have 4 wings. Most shots are well lit. ISO is set to 100. Is there a setting to fix this problem?

Comment: Welcome to Video Production. Adding some example images to your question would help people to answer it. Sounds a bit like the "rod" phenomenon, which had credulous people convinced there were rod shaped insects that were invisible to the naked eye but not to video cameras: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rod_%28optics%29

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're seeing motion blur. For stills you would increase the shutter speed. For video, you need to decrease the [shutter angle](http://www.surfacedstudio.com/tutorials/shutter-angle-tutorial). Essentially, the shutter angle determines how long the shutter is open for each frame of video. So for video at 30fps, it can never be slower than 1/30th of a second. But it can be faster!

For example at 30fps, if you set the shutter angle to 360°, you'll get 1/30th of a second for each frame of video. If you set it to 180°, you'll get 1/60th of a second, and so on.